# How can I reuse an application id on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I deleted one of my apps on GAE, let's call it my-application-id.appspot.com, with the intent of reusing the id. Before I gave the ok to delete, I got this message:

> Do you want to request permanent deletion of your application? If you
>   click the button below, you will have 72 hours to change your mind.
>   After that time, the application's data and state will be
>   inaccessible, and you cannot get it back. However, the application id
>   (my-application-id) will remain reserved approximately forever.

The last sentence implies that I can reuse the id, right? But my attempt to create a new app with this id fails. How can I reuse the id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you can't reuse it. Once an app ID is reserved, regardless of whether the app is deleted, cannot be taken for a new application.

If you'd like a memorable URL for an application, I'd suggest using a [custom domain](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).

Comment: +1 and accepted. Since you are with Google can you please push for a change in the wording I quoted above? It's the "however" that's misleading. The gist is "Your data is gone forever, HOWEVER the application id will remain reserved". This is confusing, since you're saying with some authority that in fact, data, state, AND application id are gone for good. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Will do. Apologies for the confusion.