# Where is App Engine projects after upgrading to Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I don't see any of my App Engine projects from either https://appengine.google.com/start or https://cloud.google.com/console/project.

I'm not sure if I've deleted them, while I can't create a new project with the same id.

Comment: make sure you're logged in to the correct account -- you can see the email in the upper right here: https://appengine.google.com/ . Try in an 'incognito' window.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure I logged in with the right account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that (a) you're sure you're logged in with the correct account, and (b) you don't see it in either the AppEngine or the Developers console UI, it most likely has been deleted.

Since [AppEngine disallows reuse of application ids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308718/3618671), it will prevent creating an app of the same name.

As an aside, if you remember the exact name of your AppEngine app, you can try to access it at this URL:

> https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=s~*[app-name-here]*

and if you get redirected back to the [main AppEngine page](https://appengine.google.com/), then it has been deleted.