# Can't delete app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app engine project which coun't be deleted. The project was created by ‘Duplicate Application Settings' function when migrating an application with a master-slave datastore.

Something went wrong during the migration process and I decided to delete the newly created application but had no success. I used both traditional app engine adiministration console and the new cloud platform console to delete the application but the application still be there and running after the scheduled time.

I want to reuse the application id and don't like to have an unused project in my app list. Is there any way to delete it successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: If you delete the app.. you cannot reuse the same ID, so maybe it's better to keep it and delete the uploaded versions instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16308718/8418

Comment: I had somewhat of a similar issue when migrating from the master-slave datastore. When it's done properly your old app-id becomes an alias for your new app-id. Then again: What's an app-id's value anyway? As soon as you use your own domain your app-id doesn't matter anymore. If you want to keep your old app id, do not delete it. Even if it was deleted, you cannot reuse your app id.

Comment: The application had been deleted eventually several hours ago. What Lipis and konqi mentioned were correct. The deleted app id is invalid now. The case is closed.