# gae app moving to eu-datacenter or re-opening

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cloud

I had an php app in GAE that i made. At the point only usa was available. (no selection at all)

now i have other app for the same sql-data in eu datacenter.
I want to join the 2 apps in eu and using the same cloud-sql instance.
Didn't found a way to move app from USA to EU so i deleted the app.
2 weeks have passed and i cannot create new app in eu region with the same id (same address) wtf?
I need the same address that was with the old app! I don't mind that the end part of the url is .appspot.com i won't be using my own domain at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-use the same app ID. Ever. From section 2c in
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading:

[image]

Also discussed here: [How can I reuse an application id on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306563/how-can-i-reuse-an-application-id-on-google-app-engine).

You also can't change an application from US to EU after app registration, see highlighted note right under the above-mentioned 2c paragraph:

[image]

So you can only:

- get a new app ID (in EU zone)
- update the old app code with the new app ID (where applicable) and deploy it as the new app code
- access the new app at new_app_id.appspot.com (from the EU location)