# How to selectively replicate kind(tables) in google cloud datastore to multiple regions

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, database-replication

How to selectively replicate kinds(tables) in google cloud datastore to multiple regions.
As I understand, one can create a google datastore one per project with multiple kinds.

Also while creating this datastore instance within the project, it asks right away which region you want to replicate to.

What if I want to replicate kind1 to USA region and kind2 to USA and EU region? is it possible?

Or do i have to create multiple projects with such respective policy for replication and manage it externally from another project which has the app.

I did try to dig into other posts and documentation on gcloud but did not get a clear answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For having replicated kinds in Google Cloud Datastore to multiple regions (ie. USA and EU), you should have two different Cloud Datastore across two different projects and take care of replicating the data/kinds across these applications yourself (for example by defining a [cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron)) as answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170926/google-datastore-cross-region-replication).

Also you could use Google Cloud Storage for unstructured data (for example backup storage), which supports Multi-Regional buckets and synchronize data across regions automatically.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) you could find helpful guide for choosing storage options in GCP.

Comment: Thank you. Wonder why doesn't google datastore support AWS DynamoDB Global Tables like approach.