# Trigger eventarc event ONLY when a particular cloud datastore entry is committed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, event-arc

I am currently using Cloud Datastore with cloud functions using trigger set on `cloud.datastore.v1.Commit`. However, this requires that all writes are sent to the trigger, and I woudl like to be able to filter and send data only when a particularly entity or kind is edited.

I attempted to use the path pattern described in the [public docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen#trigger_event_filters) but am not able to specify it anywhere with the `Commit` trigger in the "Cloud Datastore" provider.

Comment: On what do you want to set your filter?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere a datastore key!

Comment: You can't filter on the message content, like the key. You have to build this filter yourselves

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere we kind of have. by key, i meant the datastore kind. this is the closest to what i want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235137/how-to-selectively-replicate-kindtables-in-google-cloud-datastore-to-multiple

i want to do this real-time. would i really have to rely on a cronjob?

Comment: The resourceName is the database. If you want a finer granularity, you have to do it yourselves

Comment: Please provide examples of what triggers are not working.  The documentation https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen#trigger_event_filters shows examples of how to trigger on specific entities.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere of course I know that. What do you mean by doing it myself? I am already doing it myself in a way, but it's a very hacky shitty solution that just works.

Comment: @JimMorrison I already tried that! My kind was Users. Doing:
- `Users/*` didn't work
- `Users/**` didn't work
- `**/Users/*` didn't work
- `*/Users/*` didn't work
- `projects/{name}/databases/{databaseName}/Users/*` didn't work

i am suspicious this didn't work because the logs say something like: `projects/{name}/databases/{databaseName}/Users/{id}` meanwhile in path patterns, I used the above. Any 2 cents?

Comment: Strange you said that. I have this in my logs `resourceName: "projects/<my project id>/databases/(default)"`. I do not have the kind

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes that's the resourceName for me as well. however, i wanted it eventarc to trigger ONLY when a particular kind in it had a related database commit.

Comment: That's my point, you can't do it with Eventarc. Eventarc must trigger an endpoint for ALL the event, and you have to ack immediately the useless event, and process effectively the valid events. The bad side is you are paying for compute time just to discard useless events. I know the issue, but I havent easy and scalable solution for that.

Comment: Then that's resolved. Will discard this solution in a few, wanted to be sure. Thanks for the follow up!

Comment: It got a little confusing because https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen#trigger_event_filters looked a little promising when i discovered it first.

Comment: Hey @CodeGatherer, I wanted to check how you were trying to configure the configuration. The docs you linked show to use the newly launched triggers for Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode, which *do* support entity filter triggers. These are available in the UI under the "Cloud Firestore" event provider, where you can specify in the filter an entity path (like the examples you used above, e.g. `**/Users/*` for a kind filter).

Comment: hey @PatrickCostello ! thanks for the response. i am currently using datastore, i think that's probably not equivalent to cloud firestore and thus that's why anything in the docs didn't work. for context, `google.datastore.v1.Datastore.Commit` is the event i am looking forward to monitoring. am i still missing something that can make my life really simple?

Comment: If you use datastore today, you are (except for very special cases) using Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode ([more info](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore)).

If you select the "Cloud Firestore" event provider in your eventarc trigger flow, you'll see the option for a "google.cloud.datastore.entity.v1.updated" event type. This event type will trigger for each entity changed in your google.datastore.v1.Datastore.Commit message and supports entity-path filtering.

Comment: @PatrickCostello you're a life saver. this is the best answer here.

Comment: @CodeGatherer -- happy to help! I went ahead and added the answer (and also tried to edit the question to hopefully capture the root of the problem to make it easier for others searching for the same things -- but took some editorial liberties so please adjust as appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

If you use datastore today, you are (except for very special cases) using Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode (more info). If you select the "Cloud Firestore" event provider in your eventarc trigger flow, you'll see the option for a `google.cloud.datastore.entity.v1.updated` event type. This event type will trigger for each entity changed in your `google.datastore.v1.Datastore.Commit` message and supports entity-path filtering.

You can still use the "Cloud Datastore" event provider for events based on audit logs (however these are generally far less useful when entities are written than the entity triggers defined above.