# Google app engine hosting for SaaS app with global users - US or EU?

Tags: google-app-engine, hosting

We are currently using Google app engine hosted in US zone for our existing SaaS app. It has this customer split up - 40% from US, 40% from EU and rest from Asia.

We have a lot of EU customers asking about EU compliance and the need for data to stay in EU datacenter.

We are now building a new SaaS app. To overcome the above issue, we are planning to host it in EU instead of US (as US customers have no mandatory compliance requirements).

While this solution looks good in theory, we wanted to understand what possible repercussions this may have for our US customers?

Some of the users on this forum complained about the data delays from EU data centers in comparison to the US ones. Is there any truth in this? What other challenges may this approach pose?

We would really appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170926/google-datastore-cross-region-replication/41368308#41368308

Comment: Thanks for the link Dan. We would like to avoid deploying in 2 regions (in US and EU) as pushing updates and other maintenance gets challenging.

Comment: I understand. If so, then the answer is simple: GDPR/EU compliance requires data stored in EU, so that single app would need to be in a EU region/zone, regardless of the repercussions on US customers.