# Google Cloud Platform Registered Project cannot be accessed

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I try to map my custom domain (which is verified for ownership)
to my registered google cloud console sample project everything seems to be ok.
But when I type the URL of my custom domain it is giving the following error
Error: Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
I saw some similar questions here. But none of the answers did help.
Thanks.

Comment: Not enough info. The request appears to have hit a server. If you mapped your custom domain correctly that server is your app. So start with your app's logs and from there goto to configs, implementation, etc. as needed.

Comment: Hi Dan, Before mapping Custom Domain 'project id.appspot.com' was taking to the project's request handler. Now it is giving 404 error message. That means custom domain is not mapped to the project. Please tell me what more info you need.

Comment: The `project id.appspot.com` should continue to work regardless of the app being mapped to a custom domain or not - this allows you to debug the app. If that's not working step back and fix it, otherwise it'll be practically impossible to make progress on the custom domain front.  If it is working on `appspot.com` but not on the custom domain then logging should show if packets are making it to the app (and thus the 404 is an app functionality issue) or not (and thus the 404 is a custom domain mapping issue).

Comment: Thanks Dan. Even project id.appspot.com is giving the same error.

Comment: Duh! I mixed up things in the last phrase in my prev comment: if it's working on `appspot.com` then it's a custom domain mapping issue, otherwise it's an app functionality issue, sorry about that. So it's an app issue, fix it and make things work again on `appspot.com` first. Anything in the logs?

Comment: How to view the logs ? Nothing can be seen in the dashboard except project name and project id.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer.

Comment: You should also get used to console navigation :) - check "Tour the console" - the last popup menu list item, under the top right, 2nd to last, "3 vertical dots" menu icon on the blue cloud platform navigation bar, beside your user's icon.

Comment: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"jayanmadappatt@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"appengine.googleapis.com","methodName":"com.google.appengine.legacy.app_created","resourceName":"apps/saucy-boomerang-123-1250","serviceData":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.legacy.AuditData","eventMessage":"Created the application","eventData":{"title":"saucy-boomerang-123"}}}
{
metadata:
{…}
protoPayload:
{…}
insertId:
"2016-03-14|05:47:48.571215-07|10.106.206.199|-1240960063"
log:
"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity"
}

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in the logs. Thanks for the info Dan.

Comment: Something strange !! When I typed url 'project name.appspot.com' it is working !!. But 'project id.appspot.com' is giving error. Can I change the project id?

Comment: After deleting (shutting down) the project I tried to create the same project with another name.
Now I understand the problem is with deploying the application to the console using appcfg.py commandline command. When I use this without --oauth it will ask for the email and password. After entering the correct password it will give error 404---begin server output and exit. When I use --oauth option it gives the same error 404 and the 'This application does not exist <app_id='u'projectname>..But I gave the correct name in the app.yaml file.

Comment: No, you can't change the project ID. And you can't re-use the project ID from a previous project, even if deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306563/how-can-i-reuse-an-application-id-on-google-app-engine

Comment: In general I suggest trying to avoid handling `appcfg.py` args manually (IMHO error prone). I let it get its info from the config files and let it handle authentication using defaults - it was designed to be very flexible, but that comes at a price - sometimes it gets confusing. I only had to enter the credentials once - in the browser window that `appcfg.py` opened and it remembered them (my browser is always running when I invoke the cmd).

Comment: Sounds like you may be mixing the project ID and name. The name is a free-form string which is pretty much used only to visually identify the project in the developer console. The ID must be unique (can be auto-generated by GAE), is the one in the appspot URL (thus can't have spaces and other special chars), used in the `.yaml` config files, `appcfg.py` args, etc - pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Got the solution !!! Yes you are absolutely right 'appcfg.py' comes at

Comment: I had to give the command 'appcfg.py --application=projectID --email=myaccount --oauth update project directory'. It works! This deploys the application correctly and the mapping to custom domain also works. Thanks a lot Dan for closely following. I must thank Grace as well for directing me to this forum.

Comment: `--application=projectID` is typically redundant as that info should be in the `app.yaml` config file. It can even spell trouble if the info in the 2 places is actually conflicting, `appcfg.py`s logic for picking one over the other might not be what you're intending/expecting and potentially cause obscure app malfunctioning.

Comment: Is it? Actually I gave the project name in the app.yaml file. Here for appcfg.py  I used the project ID automatically generated by the app engine .Without that project was not uploading even if  I mention the email. Now I think for future projects edit the projectID when it is getting created and make it the same as the project name.

Comment: check `application` optional config: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Optional_elements

Comment: Thanks. Very informative. But I could not overcome that error.Though theoretically wrong it worked! I think gcloud is a better option than appcfg.py.